# Razor @Html.ActionLink not getting passed control value correctly

Tags: asp.net, razor, html.actionlink

I am new to Razor.  I am making good progress on this project but have hit a major road block with something that would seem to be easy. I have read a lot of posts about how to pass the value of a control as a parameter to a controller in order to redirect to a new view.  The problem is that I either get the value passed to the controller but can't redirect OR I redirect and the parameter is not passed.

This is my latest attempt.  I was hoping to pass the return of GetSelectedEmail to the controller (the value of "selectedEmail").  I can see that the Javascript is getting the correct value and the controller is being called, but the value is always NULL.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Get Scoring Report...", "History", "Student", null, new { onclick = "return GetSelectedEmail();" });
<select id="selectedEmail" name="align">
    @foreach( var s in Model.Students )
    {
        <option id=@s.Email>@s.Email</option>
    }
</select>

function GetSelectedEmail() {
    var str = "new {email=" + $("#selectedEmail").val() + "}";
    return str;
}
```

The controller...

```
    public ActionResult History(string email, string sort)
    {
        string localEmail="";

        if ( email == null || email == "" )
            localEmail = AccountProfile.CurrentUser.UserName;
```

...

I have also tried to call the controller with Ajax like below.  The controller does get the "selectedEmail" parameter but the page never redirects.  I just does nothing.  I tried both having the action link with the link parameters or not (show below).

```
@Html.ActionLink("Get Scoring Report...", "", "", null, new { onclick = "return GetSelectedEmail();" });
<select id="selectedEmail" name="align">
    @foreach( var s in Model.Students )
    {
        <option id=@s.Email>@s.Email</option>
    }
</select>


function GetSelectedEmail() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Student/History',
        data: { email: $("#selectedEmail").val(), sort: "CaseID" },
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
    });
    return true;
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Your first approach is not actually doing the redirection. ( also it calls a different method, which i am assuming a copy paste mistake)

Your current code is not passing the values because it is a link and when it is clicked, it is supposed to navigate to that url, which is exactly what it is doing.

I just changed the code to use unobtrusive javascript. Replaced the `onclick` with an `id` for the link

```
@Html.ActionLink("Get Scoring Report", "History", "Student", null, new { id="score" });
```

and when the click happens on this link, read the value of the select element and navigate to the second action method by setting the location.href property value

```
$(function () {

    $("#score").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();  // Stop the normal redirection

        var url = $(this).attr("href"); //Get the url to action method

        url += "?email=" + $("#selectedEmail").val(); //append querystrings

        window.location.href = url;  // redirect to that url
    });

});
```

Comment: Nice, I appreciate the response.  I see that you set the "id" of the ActionLink param to "score" and then I see how the score object's click method completes the redirection.  Could you explain how/why this structure is defined or can point me to some docs?  It looks like the "new { id="score"} is the htmlAttributes argument?

Comment: That code will generate an anchor tag with `id='score'`. Later in javascript, we can use this `Id` as the jQuery selector to wire up the click event.

Answer (score 0):

For what I needed the solution was simple.

```
<a href="#" onclick="GetScoreHistory()">Show Student Scores</a>
<select id="selectedEmail" name="align">
    @foreach( var s in Model.Students )
    {
        <option id="@s.Email">@s.LastName,@s.FirstName</option>
    }
</select>
```

And the Javascript magic...

```
function GetScoreHistory() {
    var emailVal = $('#selectedEmail').find('option:selected').attr('id');
    var url = '@Url.Action("History", "Student")';
    url += "?email=" + escape(emailVal);
    window.location.href = url;
}
```

The controller was called exactly how I needed it to be called.